# you tube api is this url valid or not - json url in end of html to get feeds

Tags: youtube-api

you tube api is this url valid or not - json url in end of html to get feeds?
if is valid if insert in browser address bar must get the feeds ?
I do not get any either in javascript code, anyway is it valid or...?

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/lynda/uploads?alt=json-in-script&max-results=30&category=Villalobos&callback=listVideos

Answer (score 0):

Is the value "Villalobos" for: &category=Villalobos an existing category for the videos of the user ?
The Base url seems to be fine (Try it with another username).
If this username does exist, then the YouTube channel-page should be: http://www.youtube.com/users/lynda. Howver, this url gives a "NOT Found" page. Then either the username does not exist or it's channel is hidden. When hidden. you need to provide authorization token with your request.